How to draw the outermost line using scatter plot and geom density line?
I want to draw the density line on the scatter plot using ggplot2.
Referencing this code, I draw the example figure below:
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(200), y = rnorm(200))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_density_2d()


The expected result is here.


What exactly do you want that outer line to represent? There's no points outside that line define a boundary. Do your data have a fixed range? Otherwise it's entirely possible to have points go off to infinity. Are you maybe looking for a convex hull of some sort? When estimating densities you often assume the variables can go off to infinity.

@MrFlick Thank you for your comment! The original data has a limited range from 0 to 1.5. I just want to visualize the density of the data from the boundary of the data.

Absent infinity, stat_chull, and rolling your own ggplot statChull.

@Chris Thank you for your comment. Although stat_chull returned the angled outline of points, it works well.

You can use a custom "break" to add contours of the density outside the range of the data. I arbitrarily chose a contour value of 0.005 based on the reciprocal of the number of points - I've highlighted it red for contrast.
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_density_2d() +
  geom_density_2d(breaks=c(0.005), col="red")



I don't know if there's a way to work out a suitable value of breaks that is guaranteed to give a single connected region that includes all the points, apart from just making it very small.

We could use ggalt::geom_encircle():
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(200), y = rnorm(200))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_density_2d() +
  geom_encircle(color = "red")


Created on 2024-07-12 with reprex v2.0.2
